# Java Thread CallBack in android

Tags: java, android, callback

For whatever reason I can't get my callback working.  Essentially I'm going to be making a group chat using a tcp server that I created.  I'm trying to create a thread in java and then use a callback to provide the information that I got from the socket back to the main activity.

The error I'm currently receiving:

```
12-04 02:53:05.969  15143-15169/com.AndroidBabble E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-4340
java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
```

But i'm not sure how to do this looper.prepare, and when I do it it doesn't seem to be working - so i'm wondering how you implement looper.prepare in the context of my code.

Here's my code:

```
public interface ResponseEvent {
  public void responseEvent();
}
```

**Main**

```
public class Main extends Activity implements ResponseEvent{
  Button btn;
  ClientTask client;
  String LOCALHOST = "localhost";
  int PORT = 5678;
  Thread thread;
  /**
   * Called when the activity is first created.
   */
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
//    Thread thread = new Thread(client = new ClientTask(this, LOCALHOST, PORT));
    client = new ClientTask(this, LOCALHOST, PORT);

  }

  public void button(View v){
    thread = new Thread(client);
    thread.start();

  }

  public void responseEvent(){
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Trig", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  }


}
```

**ClientTask**

```
public class ClientTask implements Runnable{
  public Handler mHandler;
  private ResponseEvent re;
  BufferedReader in;
  Socket socket;
  String HOSTNAME;
  int PORT;
  String scan;

  public ClientTask(ResponseEvent event, String HOSTNAME, int PORT){
    re = event;
    this.HOSTNAME = HOSTNAME;
    this.PORT = PORT;
  }

  public void run(){
 //   try {
  //    socket = new Socket(HOSTNAME, PORT);
   //   in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

      re.responseEvent();
//    } catch (IOException ex) {
    }
  }
```

Eventually I want to pass a string through the response event and it will get it in the main.

Comment: Use a Java `interface` as a callback would be a good start.

Answer (score 0):

```
 public void responseEvent(){
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Trig", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  }
```

`responseEvent` is called in your Thread's context. But the `Toast` has to be handled by the UI Thread. Since `responseEvent` is defined inside an Activity you can use runOnUiThread to post a Runnable in the UI Thread queue,

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077462/learn-java/java-tip-10--implement-callback-routines-in-java.html) explains how to use callback interfaces, i think it could be an interesting read for you.

Comment: I read this already, most of the code that is implemented in my code is also present in the post that you linked...

Answer (score 0):

You can use Looper to communicate from your background thread to the UI thread.. Try this:

```
public void responseEvent(){
    // Defines a Handler object that's attached to the UI thread
    new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Trig", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
}
```